# How do make Yesod the Key record with if a custom type is being used?

Tags: json, haskell, yesod

The situation is the following. My type definition looks like this:

```
Branch
    name String
    category String
    address Address Maybe
    qualifications [Int] Maybe
    deriving Show Read Generic
```

The Address type is defined the following way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module Models.Address where

import Database.Persist.TH
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson

data Address = Address { line1 :: String,
                         line2 :: Maybe String,
                         house_name :: Maybe String,
                         house_number :: Maybe Int,
                         cityortown :: String,
                         postalcode :: String,
                         country :: String } deriving (Show, Read, Generic)

instance ToJSON Address
instance FromJSON Address

derivePersistFieldJSON "Address"
```

However, when i send a post request, with the exact same json data as I receive (with values changed), I get a 400 Bad Request error, messaging:

```
errors: ["parsing Datatypes.Branch(Branch) failed, key "branchName" not found"]
message: "Invalid Arguments"
```

Tried to reformulate the key definitions to the standard pattern in the address defition, but it seems unrelated. What coudl be the issue?

Route definition func:

```
postBranchesP :: Key Branch -> Handler ()
postBranchesP z = do
  x <- requireCheckJsonBody
  runStderrLoggingT $ withPostgresqlPool connStr 10 $ \pool -> liftIO $ do
    flip runSqlPersistMPool pool $ do
      update z [BranchName =. branchName x, BranchCategory =. branchCategory x, BranchAddress =. branchAddress x, BranchQualifications =. branchQualifications x]
```

JSON received:

```
branchAddress:
  cityortown: "London"
  country: "United Kingdom"
  house_name: null
  house_number: 1
  line1: "Main street"
  line2: null
  postalcode: "4MN WE5"
branchCategory: "State assessments"
branchName: "Faculty of Physics & Astronomy"
branchQualifications: []
```

JSON sent

```
branchAddress:
  cityortown: "London"
  country: "United Kingdom"
  house_name: null
  house_number: 1
  line1: "Main street"
  line2: null
  postalcode: "4MN WE5"
branchCategory: "Higher education degrees"
branchName: "Faculty of Mathematics"
branchQualifications: []
```

Comment: I wasn't going to say this right away, because I'm not a yesod export and thought it might be possible that this was enough info for a yesod expert to help. But since you haven't gotten any takers, I'll say it now... You need to give us a minimal reproducible example. "Minimal" means strip down the data definitions and other code as much as possible. "Reproducible" means a complete, compilable program, together with the exact actions/input you give it. With that information, I suspect even non-yesod experts will be able to chime in.

Comment: Show us the JSON you are receiving.